# web api with jquery ajax - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-404

I am trying to call a web api service from a mvc client.
After several errors that I've managed to solve, I am stuck on: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)".

**My routing:**

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/**{action}**/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

**The web api:**

```
public class TestServicesController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetTest()
        {

            Console.Write("SUCCESS!!!!!");
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
    }
```

**the client:**

```
function test1() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:52285/api/Services/GetTest",
            type: 'GET',
            success: function () { alert("success!!"); },
        });
    }
```

I have tried searching for that problem, nothing worked.. please help!

Comment: Is your WebAPI and MVC client on the same server (i.e. localhost:52285)?  I just want to eliminate any possibility of cross domain requests (which I know wouldn't cause the 404, but still, it would be good to know if they're on the same server or separate servers).

Comment: They are not on the same server. I had cross domain problems, but I solved that by adding 
<customHeaders>
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:52274"/>
    </customHeaders>

Comment: Have you tried using Fiddler to debug this?  I discovered Fiddler some time ago, and it's so useful when trying to figure out why GET/PUT/POST/etc. requests aren't successful. http://fiddler2.com/

Comment: I am not sure what I am looking for there.. Is there a way to figure out was is the path to the service, from the project?

Comment: The path to the service, your WebAPI in other words, should be simple to find out. It's simply your WebAPI project > controller > action. Look in your WebAPI project, at your controller. Does this make sense?  Basically: http://server/WebAPI project/controller/action/optional parameters

Answer (score 1):

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static HttpResponseMessage GetTest()
    {

        Console.Write("SUCCESS!!!!!");
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

One thing I noticed is that the GetTest method is not static and without WebMethod attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue and following change in Global.asax.cs worked for me.

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register); //You need to add this line
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```